# Xamarin Forms: How Can i Pass Media File From a content page (popup) to another content page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Please i am using Rg.Plugins.Popup to perform operation. I capture photo from it. the photo is stored in a MediaFile object. I want to pass the value of the MediaFile to my main page where the popup is called from.

```
**public MediaFile _mediaFile;**

public async void ChoosePhotoEvent()
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "This is not support on your device.", "OK");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var mediaOption = new PickMediaOptions()
            {
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                CompressionQuality = 10,
                CustomPhotoSize = 30
            };
            **_mediaFile** = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
            if (_mediaFile == null) return;

        }
    }
```

The code above shows the **_mediaFile** i get the data from. how can i pass value in this _mediaFile to another content page so i can show the image in the next page?

The other page has a StackLayout that expects the data

```
<StackLayout  Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="80" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image  x:Name="capturedImage" Source="ic_add_a_photo.png" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsVisible="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    
                </Grid>

            </StackLayout >
```

The x:Name="CapturedImage" needs to hold the value of the _mediafile coming from the popUp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the **Stream** as the parameter to the next page .

#### in the method ChoosePhotoEvent

```
var source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = _mediaFile.GetStream();
        return stream;
    });
```

#### in another content page

Define a new constructor with the argument

```
public xxxContentPage(ImageSource source)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   
    capturedImage.Source = source;
}
```

And when you want to popup the page

```
 this.Navigation.xxxContentPage(new xxxContentPage(source));
```

### Update

In your case you could use MessagingCenter to pass data to last page .In this way you don't need to set navigation .

```
var source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = _mediaFile.GetStream();
        return stream;
    }); 
MessagingCenter.Send<Object, ImageSource>(this,"finish",source);
```

#### in the last page

```
public Faultz()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  // ...
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, ImageSource>(this, "finish", (arg, source) => 
   {
            
            
         capturedImage.Source = source;       
            
   });
}
```

Comment: Zhang thanks for your time. this approach seems to be the solution. However, i am using Rg.Plugins.Popup. to Pop and pass data to the other page i presently use await 'PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();'  i tried passing the constructor and inside like u mentioned as await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(new Faultz(source)); but i still have issue as it expects a bool. How do i achieve that ?

Comment: My code is just for demo , you should modify it as you need in your case .

Comment: Please can u show a snippet on how to pass that? i see confused in that. i think that is the only remaining thing to get the issue solved

Comment: Rg.Plugins.Popup and native navigation are similar .

Comment: 'public async void CancelEvent()
        {
           PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(new Faultz(source));
        }'

This is the code for my navigation. Falutz is my construtor on the other page which takes the argument ImageSouce source

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly?

Comment: ` public async void ChoosePhotoEvent()
        {
                _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                if (_mediaFile == null) return;
                // capturedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => _mediaFile.GetStream());
                // capturedImage.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }`

Comment: So you want to pass the data to the last page ?

Comment: ` public async void CancelEvent()
        {
           var source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = _mediaFile.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });

            PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(new Faultz(source));
        }`

Comment: Yes i want to pass data to the last page which the popup is on. when i close the popup the page behind shld have the image.